# DOORS DXL Script to export objects from the current view to another module

Tags: ibm-doors

I would like to export objects from the current view to another module via DXL Script.

```
string targetModuleName = "";
string targetModulePath = "";


ModName_ mod = current
Object o
for o in mod do {
    if (isInView(o)) {
        // Objekt in das Zielmodul exportieren
        Module targetModule = edit(targetModuleName, true)
        o."export"(targetModule, false)
    }
}


Module targetModule = open(targetModulePath)
targetModule."import"(mod)
```

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Without writing all of the code for you, which would require understanding a huge set of underlying assumptions. Some things to consider:

The *for* loop construction you used already respects the current display set, so you don't need to do an additional check on whether the object is in view.

By "export" of an object I'm assuming that you want to copy that object into another module. The only real way to do this in DOORS I believe is to create an object in your other module and then copy the contents of the original object into the contents of your new module.

To create an object in the new module you can use the following declarations which returns a reference to the Object that is created:

> Object create(Module m) - creates as first object in module m
>
> Object create(Object o) - creates at same level and immediately after o
>
> Object create(below(Object o)) - creates as first child of object o

Then to assign attributes you can use the following:
o1."(Attribute Definition Name)" = o2."(Attribute Definition Name)"""

Where o1 is the new object, o2 is the original object, and replace (Attribute Definition Name) with the name of the attribute you are copying.

Hope that's somewhat helpful! Good luck!